# Why is my Discord.py bot's command_prefix not updating after I update MySQL unless I restart the bot?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to use a MySQL database to store prefixes for different servers. When I use a command to update the prefix in the DB it does work as I can see the change in MySQL but when I try to use the new prefix it seems that command_prefix is not updating since the new prefix doesn't work, UNLESS I restart the bot. Please help? Here's the code below:

main.py:

```
db = mysql.connector.connect(
        host='localhost',
        user='root',
        password='',
        database='nashudb'
)

cursor = db.cursor(dictionary=True)

def get_server_prefix(client, message):

        cursor.execute(f"SELECT PREFIX from prefixes where ID = {message.guild.id}")

        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        for row in rows:
                return row["PREFIX"]

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=get_server_prefix, intents=discord.Intents.all())
```

set prefix command:

```
    @commands.hybrid_command(name="prefix", description="Change prefix Nashu uses!")
    async def prefix(self, ctx, *, newprefix: str):
     
        sql = "UPDATE prefixes SET PREFIX = %s WHERE ID = %s"
        val = (newprefix, str(ctx.guild.id))
        cursor.execute(sql, val)

        db.commit()
     
        await ctx.send("Prefix changed! :3")
```

I've tried using cursor.fetchone() method instead since I'm only trying to get one row(?) I'm new to SQL and not really sure but that didn't work either. I used a JSON file before and it worked fine. Thanks in advance!